# How to connect to remote machine from within protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, storage

I am trying to automate testcases for one of our web-application using protractor. These are complex testcases and sometime also require to connect to test clients(can be Windows/Linux machines).

I use web-application to configure storage(e.g. creating luns and mapping it to a test client). Configuring storage system using web-application can be done using protractor. I just don't know how can i connect to test client from within the protractor to perform some operation on test clients (e.g. check if luns are visible).

Is it possible to do connect to test clients from within protractor? 
If yes, test clients can be a windows or Linux os. What is the ways to do it for both types of OS.

I am using Jasmine as test framework and javascript as language within protractor.

If something is not clear, please ask. Any help is highly appreciated

Edit:
After looking at the comments and answers provide by @Gunderson and @GoLGo13 i think my question doesnt provide the complete info.

There is no web-application for my test clients which i can use. I have to use either ssh(in case of linux) or powershell(in case of windows) to connect to clients and perform operations. What i want is to execute perl/powershell code from within protractor, including making connection to test clients.

Comment: you probably want a [selenium grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp).  Tests are sent to the hub and the hub routes those tests to a specific node based on the capabilities you specify

Answer (score 0):

In order to test on multiple operating systems, you will need to setup a [Selenium Grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp).

The main Selenium server which all of your tests will connect to will be the **"HUB"**. The **HUB** will be installed on one main machines that all other computers should have network access to.

Then you will configure Selenium servers on each of your operating system machines, such as Windows and Linux. Each one of those operating system machines will be configured using a **.json** configuration file that looks like this:

```
{
    "capabilities":
    [
      {
        "browserName": "safari",
        "maxInstances": 5,
        "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
      },
      {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "maxInstances": 5,
        "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
      },
      {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "maxInstances": 5,
        "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
      }
    ],
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 5,
    "port": 5555,
    "host": null,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4723,
    "hubHost": "localhost"
}
```

When you start those operating system Selenium servers, they will connect automatically to the **HUB** if configured properly.

You then will be able to access your hub through the **Grid Console** that looks like: **hub_computer_ip_address:port_you_chose/grid/console**.

[image: Grid Console Example]

It takes a bit of work, but is worth investing time in. Hope this intro to Selenium Grid helps!

Comment: Now I think my question doesnt provide the complete info. There is no web-application for my test clients. I have to use either ssh(in case of linux) or powershell(in case of windows) to connect to clients and perform operations. What i want to do is execute perl/powershell code from within protractor, including making connection to test clients.